Find the range of a which can let ellipse and parabola below intersect
The ellipse $x^2 + 4(y-a)^2 = 4$ intersects(1 or 2 points) the parabola $x^2 = 2y$($Y^2=2X$  Before,and by Desmos they intersect at one point when $a=-1$ at least).
Find the range of $a$.
My attempt:
By $x^2 = 2y$,the ellipse equation turns to :
$$2y^2 + (1-4a)y + 2a^2 -2 = 0$$
Then,$\Delta = (1-4a)^2 - 8(2a^2-2) \implies -8a + 17$
As ellipse intersects parabola,$\Delta \ge 0$,then we obtain:
$$a \le \frac{17}{8}$$
The answer:
Let $x = 2cos\theta$, and $y = a + sin\theta$
Then after canceling and combining like terms,the ellipse equation turns to:
$$4cos\theta^2 = 2(a + sin\theta) \implies a=2cos\theta^2 - sin\theta \implies -2sin(\theta+\frac14)^2 + \frac{17}{8}$$
Since $-1 \le sin\theta \le 1$,we have:
$$0 \le (sin\theta + \frac14)^2 \le \frac{25}{16}$$
Then,$$-1 \le a \le \frac{17}{8}$$
My problem:
Why can't I obtain $a \ge -1$? And why does it work to let $x = 2cos\theta$?
this problem is from one competition(2007,in China,for Senior Grade Three Students,though this is not its formal name,but I think it may be of some help),I made typos.

I don't think this is correct. Whatever the answer is, by symmetry of the equations, which would be easier to see if you plot their graphs — an ellipse and the parabola, it's gotta be symmetric for $a$. For example, something like "$-17/8 \leqslant a \leqslant 17/8$". I'm not saying that this is the answer, as I didn't solve the problem. I'm only saying that by a quick observation it's gotta be something like that.

Let $\mathcal{E}_a:  x^2+4(y-a)^2=4$ and $\mathcal{P}: y^2=2x$.
So if $(b,c) \in
\mathcal{E}a\cap \mathcal{P}$ then $(b,-c) \in
\mathcal{E}{-a}\cap \mathcal{P}$, so the set of all $a$ must be symetric with respect to $0$.

Now I'm even more certain that you made some typos somewhere in the question. The range for $a$ would be determined by the fact that the ellipse and the parabola are tangent to each other. But if you graph them (say, in Desmos) with $a = 17/8$, they still intersect at two points. The actual value of $a$ (its extreme values, I mean), according to Mathematica, is $a \approx \pm2.39354$, which come from solving a cubic equations that doesn't have rational roots.

Onebytheside, write in your post what you tried in order to solve your exercise, otherwise your post will be closed very soon.

@zipirovich,You're right,I wrote $x^2 = 2y$ as ${\color{red}y}^{\color{red}2}{\color{red}=}{\color{red}2}{\color{red}x}$

You solved for $y$, and that's fine, but $x^2=2y$, hence real solutions exist only if $y\ge0$. You must add this condition to get $a\ge-1$.

so what should I do?
